# JSF request.login() without password

Tags: jsf, authentication

I have a JSF application I have configured with a JPASecurityRealm I use to log users in. This works fine with native user accounts. I now added a login with facebook functionality. When users login with facebook for the first time, I create them a new native user account for our website with the data returned by facebook. Which works fine, but I have problems authenticating the user on our server now. Usually I use request.login(userID,userPassword); but because users don't have a password with their native account now, I don't know how to authenticate them? Is there something like request.login(userID), which logs the user in without needing a password?

Answer (score 1):

> but because users don't have a password with their native account now,
>   I don't know how to authenticate them? Is there something like
>   request.login(userID), which logs the user in without needing a
>   password?

You could generate a random password, persist it and notify them. Then just also give them the possibility to change it later .